# Counterexample to convergence of moments implies convergence in distribution

Tags: probability

This is from Rosenthal as an example of a distribution that isn't uniquely determined by its moments, i.e. there are two distributions that have the same moments. [image]

I'm wondering how you would ever come up with that.

Comment: May I ask where is the picture from? Thanks!